Two P-Channel MOSFETs for battery disconnection during charging
The logic is as follows: VBUS is a USB input, by default not connected at all. B+ - load output. However, when USB is connected, B+ will be replaced by it. So I need to disconnect the battery and charge it while VBUS is connected. Is this scheme correct? Q2 is needed here to avoid using a diode and to reduce the power consumption.

Oh yes, I forgot to point out on the diagram - the 2nd battery terminal is connected to the common GND

All that VBUS is doing here is turning the Q1 on, and then Q2 when its body diode conducts to its source pin. VBUS itself is not charging anything as there is no path for its current to the battery. And I don't see the need for Q2 here, as the Q1 naturally blocks power from going towards load B+.

@Edin Fifić VBUS has positive potential and disable Q1 & Q2, but! VBUS connect to B+ through ams1117 -> power leak to battery if we remove Q2. I decided that using two mosfets was better than losing 0.3 watts on a diode instead of Q2

I still don't see how is the current going through Q1 towards B+ if VBUS is off/down.

@EdinFifić from B+.. thru parasitic diode

Your explanation was a bit unclear, so I assumed B+ was just a load for the battery, and not being connected to another power supply.

@EdinFifićI said that somewhere in the post, but okay, you get the point. In that case, is this scheme approved? :)

@minto have you tried simulating it?

@Andyaka Yeah, right now. The transistors are fully closed/open. And there is no leakage.

So, do you have your answer?

@minto It seems to be OK.

@Andyaka yep, thanks a lot

That should work as long as the MOSFETs are fully turned on by the battery voltage (Vgs in data sheet for the Rds(on) value).
Not sure it makes a difference but normally the two MOSFETs are connected source-to-source, not drain-to-drain.

mosfets are connected so that there is no leakage through parasitic diodes
